# Why do we not use a (*) when accessing the value of a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, dynamic

Our professor taught us to use an indirection operator (*) when accessing a dynamic variable. Hence, I fail to understand why the code is written like this:

```
cout << arr[i];
```

And not like this:

```
cout << *arr[i];
```

Here is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    int *arr;

    cout << "Please enter size: ";
    cin >> size;

    arr = new int[size];

    cout << "Enter " << size << " items" << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "You entered: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, you are missing the `delete[]` at the end. If you dont want to write it, you can use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays like you have:

```
arr = new int[size];
```

The syntax:

```
arr[5];
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
*(arr+5)
```

It's just nicer looking.

Comment: And the professor I had for CS101 (introduction to C) in the mid-90s would knock off points if you _ever_ used the [] or -> operators. And he never gave what I consider a convincing argument as to why, just "because I can".

Comment: World's full of strange people, @SoronelHaetir . Warning to those that follow. Because of the rules outlined in the post above, you can take a pointer to a single object and use it as an array to very unfortunate effects. Say you have `int x;` and then you `int * xp = &x;` to get a pointer to `x`. Now you can `xp[1] = 42;` and write over memory that is one integer past `x`. Not a good idea. Syntactically correct, so it compiles, but logically incorrect. This is a nice example: https://ideone.com/n4ZcaP. IDEOne tells you you screwed up. Don't count on this level of niceness. C++ is cruel.